# how to make event title appear in multiple lines full calendar version 5 (resource timeline view)

Tags: html, css, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler, fullcalendar-5

this is my initial view of calendar

```
initialView: 'resourceTimelineFiveDays',
```

Here is my code . I have added  white space to be normal, even then its not working.
I don't know the error.

```
.fc-event-title{
white-space: normal;
},
.fc-event-title-container{
height:25px;
white-space: normal;
}
```

Comment: What exact effect are you trying to get? You want to split the event title across multiple lines when it contains multiple words, or something? Please give a specific example of what you're aiming for. "Not working" doesn't help us to understand anything. Thanks.

Comment: My event title is more than 30 words. it only displays one line of code (3 words) depending upon the slot duration width. I want my full title to display in multiple lines.

Comment: I think actually that's just too big for a title. A better UI would be to have a short title, and then a custom "description" field containing the extra detail, and set a popover which shows when the event is clicked (or maybe hovered) and contains the description and any other details you might want. That's how people usually deal with this situation.

Comment: The event heights are fixed programmatically by the height of a parent element (in the timeline view, anyway), in order for layout to be achieved neatly, so it's not something you can easily change.

Answer (score -1):

simple you can use html Tag '< br >' new Line for example: let title = "invoice "+ 1556 + '< br >'+ 'Total Value'+'$1500';